# Decorate general controller actions

Tags: php, design-patterns, decorator

I would like to decorate every controller action that I have in my project.
I would like to start a custom logger engine and stop it every time an action method is called.

Like this:

```
class HomeController
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {
         Logger:start();
         someLogicInThere();
         ...
         Logger:end();
    }
}
```

I would like to automate that extending to some class or something like this.

My final class controller will look like this:

```
class HomeController extends ControllerDecorator
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {
         someLogicInThere();
         ...
    }
}
```

BTW: the logger stuff doesn't really matter. My question is more a design pattern issue

Any great idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in methods beforeAction (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail) and afterAction (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#afterAction-detail), inside your ControllerDecorator.
This way you would be able to decorate every class tha extends ControllerDecorator.

ps: I'm assuming you are using Yii. Right?

Comment: Then I think you should take a look here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html. In particular pay attention to the method init(). It works as a hook for every action of your controller. Is that what you were searching for?

Comment: This is not a bad idea (using pre and post dispatch) but in this methods I don't have enough information about the real action called (like the method name, arguments, etc...).

Comment: Isn't the $request object available from the scope of the preDispatch method? I never used ZF but as far as I know this should be expected ... I will dig more and try to find out more informations about that.

Comment: @SomethingWicked Like I've written: Use a controller plugin and you have access to the request object.

Comment: `public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
        $request->getActionName()) 
 $request->getParam('param')
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called [Cross-cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern). One way to handle this is by [Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

You can fake this in PHP >= 5.4 with [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

```
trait Logger
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'logging before<br>';

        parent::indexAction();

        echo 'logging after<br>';
    }
}

class HomeControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
         echo 'indexAction<br>';
    }
}

class HomeController extends HomeControllerBase
{
    use Logger;
}

$homeController = new HomeController();
$homeController->indexAction();
```

As an experiment I've automated this process of writing a base class:

https://github.com/bitworking/AOP

I would not really use this in production because it needs to much resources.

Better look into AOP frameworks that parses the doctype and caches the new created class.
Not tested:

http://go.aopphp.com/

https://github.com/AOP-PHP/AOP

Another way to handle cross cutting concerns is to use [event driven programming](http://de.slideshare.net/cjsaylor/event-driven-application). This does not separate it 100% like AOP but it's a more approved design pattern especially in PHP.

Comment: I don't want to do it every time I create an action in every controller. Trait idea is great btw. I would like something more 'automatic'

Comment: ok, if you need to call the same methods on every action I would consider to write a [controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) and use the `preDispatch` ans `postDispatch` hooks.

Comment: [here](http://www.masterzendframework.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/zenddispatch_en.png) you see a nice graphic with the complete dispatch process.

Comment: what about completely isolated services?

Comment: @Mauro what exactly do you mean? the controller plugin IS isolated.

Comment: else I would recommend to use ZF2 where you have more possibilites (events) and it's easier to completely separate the services (service locator).

Comment: I'm talking about decorate every every method inside one class. Doesn't matter if private, protected or public. Is that possible?